# Solr - how to plan field boosting

Tags: solr, solr4

I query using

```
qf=Name+Tag
```

Now I want that documents that have the phrase in tag will arrive first so I use

```
qf=Name+Tag^2
```

and they do appear first.

What should be the rule of thumb regarding the number that comes after the field? 
How do I know what number to set it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number is pure preference based and is mainly trial and error basis.
As to how much the field weighs in comparison to the other field.
The scoring takes into account various factors, however some factors can be considered and tested 
e.g. term frequency - So is a word appears twice in Name should it override a single occurrence in the tag field

Also, if you are checking for a Phrase match you should use `pf` if using the edismax parser.

`qf` will match individuals words where `pf` will match whole words.

For e.g. if you have fields name & tag and you search for ruby rails
`qf` would cause scoring name:ruby tag:ruby & name:rails tag:rails
`pf` would cause scoring name:"ruby rails" tag:"ruby rails"

so would be better to use `qf` to match the results and boost single matches but have higher pf values.

Comment: I am definitely getting answers for fq that I dont get for qf. When I query "select?q=asd" i dont get any answer using pf

Comment: Pf can't be used alone and has to used with qf. Pf is for boosting only